# Can I put a UIPageControl inside table header of a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipagecontrol

When I looked into this *way* back in iOS5, there were a lot of problems mixing tableViews with pageControls - possible to do but buggy implementation. I'm wondering if that's still the case.

I saw a lot of questions on SO about a *tableView* inside a *pageControl*, but I'm asking about the inverse. Specifically:

Is it possible to put a UIPageControl inside the tableView Header of a UITableViewController?

Yellow outline is the tableViewHeader, blue is scrollable tableView:

[image: sketch]

Comment: I think it's as simple as adding any another view to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add custom UIPageControl in table header and than add to headerview like I add label into headerview.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     // ...
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
     //...
     UIPageControl *page = [UIPageControl alloc]init];
     //...
     [headerView addSubview:page];
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
     // ...
}
```

Comment: You're just adding a UIPageControl... how can it work?